# Flutter UI stuck when calling to base64encode

Tags: dart, flutter

I develop a screen in flutter which sending an image to my node.js server.
I have a File(from image_picker package) and I want to convert the image to base64 string.

I wrote this code:

```
List<int> imageBytes = await widget.picture.readAsBytes();
String base64Image = base64Encode(imageBytes);
```

and when the function base64Encode start, the UI of my application get stuck.

I didn't find async function and dart does not have threads so I really don't know what to do.

Anyone familiar with the problem?

Comment: Threads in Dart can be used via Isolate. They currently can't access plugins though. So for example you can't access shared preferences or Firebase from an Isolate directly. The `compute` function is an easy way to run code in another isolate bit doesn't support async results.

Comment: in addition to what Gunter said [here](https://flutter.io/docs/cookbook/networking/background-parsing#4-move-this-work-to-a-separate-isolate) you have how to use `compute`